# Replace string with output of command, different each time

Tags: linux, sed

I have many files and I want to replace the class names with a UUID. I figured out this

```
sed -i -r "s/ Class \w(\w|\d)+/ Class C$(python -c 'import uuid;print(uuid.uuid4().hex)')/"
```

It works fine when the pattern only occurs once in each file. However if the pattern occurs more than once, each occurence is replaced by the same number.

Class1.vb

```
Public Class Class1
    Public ReadOnly Property P As String = "hello"
End Class

Public Class Class2
    Public ReadOnly Property P As String = "hello"
End Class
```

```sh
$ sed -r "s/ Class \w(\w|\d)+/ Class C$(echo $RANDOM)/" Class1.vb
Public Class C27244
        Public ReadOnly Property P As String = "hello"
End Class

Public Class C27244
        Public ReadOnly Property P As String = "hello"
End Class
```

I expect the two classes to have different names. How do I fix my script?

Comment: I don't think you can do this with `sed`. It doesn't have variables that you can increment for each match. `awk` would be better for this.

Comment: @Barmar I assume $RANDOM or UUID give me enough uniqueness.

Comment: Remember, variable substitution happens *before* the command runs. `sed` just gets the literal value, it can't change it for each match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk '{gsub(/Class [[:alnum:]]+/, "Class C" int(9999*rand()))} 1' Class1.vb
Public Class C2377
    Public ReadOnly Property P As String = "hello"
End Class

Public Class C5854
    Public ReadOnly Property P As String = "hello"
End Class
```

The above will give you the same random numbers in the same order each time.  If you want different random numbers each time you run the program, use:

```
awk -v s=$RANDOM 'BEGIN{srand(s)} {gsub(/Class [[:alnum:]]+/, "Class C" int(9999*rand()))} 1' Class1.vb
```

#### How it works

- `gsub(/Class [[:alnum:]]+/, "Class C" int(9999*rand()))`

  This looks for occurrences of the regex `Class [[:alnum:]]+` and replaces each one with the concatenation of the string `Class C` and a four-digit random number calculated from `int(9999*rand())`.  A new random number is generated for each line.
- `1`

  This is awk's cryptic shorthand for print-the-current-line.

Comment: That's very nice. I'm not familiar with awk or sed.. Can you briefly talk about why awk is better than sed in this use case? Is it because as  Barmar says, sed gets the subsitution string before running it?

Comment: @QiqiGu Briefly, awk has a built-in random number generator and sed doesn't.  With your sed code, for example, it is bash that generates the random number and that number is generated __once__ before the sed command starts to run.  With awk, we can run the random number generator again for each line encountered.

Answer (score 2):

More as a proof of concept than a serious alternative: a GNU sed solution.

```sh
sed -E -e '/Class \w+/{h;s/.*/bash -c "echo C\\$RANDOM"/;e' \
    -e 'G;s/(.*)\n(.*Class )\w+(.*)/\2\1\3/}' infile
```

resulting in

```
Public Class C24276
    Public ReadOnly Property P As String = "hello"
End Class

Public Class C28554
    Public ReadOnly Property P As String = "hello"
End Class
```

Here is how it works:

```sh
/Class \w+/ {                           # If the line matches "Class <name>"
    h                                   # Copy pattern space to hold space
    s/.*/bash -c "echo C\\$RANDOM"/     # Write Bash command into pattern space
    e                                   # Replace pattern space with command output
    G                                   # Append hold space to pattern space
    s/(.*)\n(.*Class )\w+(.*)/\2\1\3/   # Swap class name with random number
}
```

Remarks:

- This uses GNU extensions: notably the `\w` character class and the `e` command.

  - [`\w` includes digits](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#regexp-extensions), so there is no need for `(\w|\d)`.
- The one-liner version is split into two commands using `-e` because [the `e` command](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-GNU-extensions_002c-evaluating-Bourne_002dshell-commands-1) cannot be followed by anything, or that anything is interpreted as the command.
- The command to be run can't just be `echo C$RANDOM` because the `e` command uses `sh` instead of Bash, and `sh` might not have `$RANDOM` (like on Ubuntu, where `sh` is dash).
- Because the command is in double quotes, the `$` in `$RANDOM` has to be escaped, and because sed does a first pass before the shell sees the command, is has to be escaped twice. Alternatively, I could have used

  ```sh
  s/.*/bash -c '\''echo C$RANDOM'\''/
  ```

  to single quote the command, but that's not very readable either.

Comment: haha, nice. just a minor issue, that class name cannot start with a number, that's why I prefixed it with C.

Comment: I had a very similar task, to replace a string ‘UUIDNEEDED’ with a uuid. As a command, I'm using ‘uuidgen’. I'm supplying the variant I used as inspiration for others: `sed -i -E -e '/UUIDNEEDED/{h;s/.*/uuidgen/;e' -e 'G;s/(.*)\n(.*)UUIDNEEDED/\2\1/}' infile` (all on one line).